# What is the most canonical way to write a for loop in AutoHotKey?

Tags: for-loop, autohotkey

There seem to be multiple different ways to write a for loop in autohotkey. The autohotkey forum [lists](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=4259) [many](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/134160-how-to-write-for-loop-in-ahk/) [different](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/108607-where-can-i-learn-about-for-loop-statements-in-autohokey/) [ways](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/119736-for-loop-like-c/).

Given me wanting to replicate what can be done in a [python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) for loop with

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(i)
```

Or in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) via:

```
  for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {System.out.print(i)}
```

What's the best way to do the same thing in autohotkey. If you read your collegues code, which way do you wish they would have used for the example of a for-loop that goes through the numbers 1 to 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AHK the [for loop](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/For.htm) is used for looping through an [array](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm)'s contents
 or, more generally, for repeating a command or a series of commands once for each key-value pair in an [object](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm).

In this case, using [Loop](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm) and A_Index is the simplest and most efficient method:

```
; go through the numbers 1 to 10: 

Loop 10
    MsgBox %A_Index%
```